# OpenAL Soft - Loop with Intro

Tags: loops, buffer, openal-soft

I have been using OpenAL soft for Win32, and I I ran into a particular problem.

My goal is to play a looping sound that has a one-shot intro portion, similar to a .WAV file with a loop marker.  As I understand it, this must be achieved in OpenAL by using multiple buffers on a source.  In general, my approach is to queue up both buffers, then wait until the second buffer is playing, and set the source to loop.  This works, but the problem is that once I am ready to stop the sound, I don't seem to be able to unqueue the last buffer.  My code looks roughly like this:

```
// set up the sound
alSourceQueueBuffers(source, 1, &buffer1);
alSourceQueueBuffers(source, 1, &buffer2);
alSourcePlay(source);

...

// check to loop sound in update
ALint buffer;
alGetSourcei(source, AL_BUFFER, &buffer);
if (buffer == buffer2)
{
    alSourcei(source, AL_LOOPING, true);
}

..

// check to stop sound in update
if (shouldStop)
{
    alSourcei(source, AL_LOOPING, false);
    alSourceStop(source);

    alSourceUnqueueBuffers(source, 1, &buffer1);
    alSourceUnqueueBuffers(source, 1, &buffer2); // AL_INVALID_OPERATION
}
```

The result seems to be that the buffer is not properly unqueued, and will be heard the next time I play this source.  I know that typically you can only unqueue a buffer after it finished playing, but I would think that I could freely unqueue any buffers on a stopped sound.  I am wondering if perhaps my use of the loop flag is causing this behavior?

I'd greatly appreciate any advice.

Thank you,
Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is a way around this.  I can't unqueue the playing buffer, but I can completely clear out the queue with this line:

```
alSourcei(source, AL_BUFFER, AL_NONE);
```

This will work just fine after stopping the sound.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the proper use of `alSourceUnqueueBuffers(source, 1, &buffer1);` is to create an array of your buffers and send it in, instead of calling it twice, you call it once on the array like so:

```
ALuint buffers[2] = { buffer1, buffer2 };
alSourceUnqueueBuffers(source, 2, buffers);
```

Note we are using a size of 2 to indicate 2 buffers.